# NKE socket filter (MacOS): can't properly re-inject the output packets

Tags: c++, c, macos, linux-kernel, kernel-extension

I'm having a problem in MacOS when using a kernel extension that should filter network traffic.

- The kext (through the sftl_filter) starts to filter all packets, and
  sends them to a process in userspace
- The client performs some operations (in this case, it simply sends the packet data back to the driver unmodified)
- The driver re-injects the modified packet back into the network stream

Incoming data works great. However, uploading data larger than 500kb results in an abruptly closed connection. Smaller files can be uploaded without issue. This is via any protocol, tested on ftp, http, https, etc.

Simplified driver code:

```
errno_t tl_data_fn(void *cookie, socket_t so, const struct sockaddr *addr, mbuf_t *data, mbuf_t *control, sflt_data_flag_t flags, FilterSocketDataDirection direction) {     
    if (check_tag(data, gidtag, FILTER_TAG_TYPE, direction == FilterSocketDataDirectionIn ? IN_DONE : OUT_DONE)) {  
        return 0;  
    }  

    if (!cookie) return result;  

    filter_cookie *f_cookie = get_filter_cookie(cookie);  

    FilterNotification notification;   
    if (direction == FilterSocketDataDirectionIn) {  
        notification.event = FilterEventDataIn;  
    } else {  
        notification.event = FilterEventDataOut;  
    }  
    notification.socketId = (uint64_t)so;  
    notification.inputoutput.dataSize = (uint32_t)mbuf_pkthdr_len(*data);  

    mbuf_copydata(*data, offset, notification.inputoutput.dataSize, notification.inputoutput.data);  

    ctl_enqueuedata(f_cookie->ctl_ref, f_cookie->ctl_unit, &notification, sizeof(FilterNotification), CTL_DATA_EOR);  

    mbuf_freem(*data);  

    if (control != NULL && *control != NULL)  
        mbuf_freem(*control);  

    return EJUSTRETURN;  
}  

errno_t tl_data_in_fn(void *cookie, socket_t so, const struct sockaddr *from, mbuf_t *data, mbuf_t *control, sflt_data_flag_t flags) {  
    return tl_data_fn(cookie, so, from, data, control, flags, FilterSocketDataDirectionIn);  
}  

errno_t tl_data_out_fn(void *cookie, socket_t so, const struct sockaddr *to, mbuf_t *data, mbuf_t *control, sflt_data_flag_t flags) {  
    return tl_data_fn(cookie, so, to, data, control, flags, FilterSocketDataDirectionOut);  
}  



errno_t ctl_send(kern_ctl_ref ctl_ref, u_int32_t unit, void *unitinfo, mbuf_t m, int flags) {      
    FilterClientResponse response;  
    mbuf_copydata(m, 0, sizeof(response), &response);  

    mbuf_t data;  
    mbuf_allocpacket(MBUF_WAITOK, response.dataSize, NULL, &data);  
    mbuf_copyback(data, 0, response.dataSize, response.data, MBUF_WAITOK);  
    set_tag(&data, gidtag, FILTER_TAG_TYPE, response.direction == FilterSocketDataDirectionIn ? IN_DONE : OUT_DONE);  

    if (response.direction == FilterSocketDataDirectionIn) {  
        sock_inject_data_in((socket_t)response.socketId, NULL, data, NULL, 0);  
    } else {  
        sock_inject_data_out((socket_t)response.socketId, NULL, data, NULL, 0);  
    }  

    mbuf_freem(m);  
    return 0;  
}
```

`tl_data_in_fn` and `tl_data_out_fn` functions are used in `sftl_filter`. `ctl_send` is used in `kern_ctl_reg` as `ctl_send_func`.

Simplified userspace process code:

```
int s = socket(PF_SYSTEM, SOCK_DGRAM, SYSPROTO_CONTROL);  

//connect to driver  

FilterNotification notification;  
while (recv(s, &notification, sizeof(FilterNotification), 0) == sizeof(FilterNotification)) {  
    FilterClientResponse response;  
    response.socketId = notification.socketId;  
    response.direction = (notification.event == FilterEventDataIn) ? FilterSocketDataDirectionIn : FilterSocketDataDirectionOut;  
    response.dataSize = notification.inputoutput.dataSize;  
    memcpy(response.data, notification.inputoutput.data, notification.inputoutput.dataSize);  
    send(s, &response, sizeof(response), 0);  
}
```

Any help / advice would be appreciated. [Kext and userspace process repository](https://github.com/LawlietRyuzakiCode/NKETest).

Thank you

Comment: Check the return value from `ctl_enqueuedata()` in the kext. You might be dropping packets. Let me know if that's not the problem, in which case I'll take a closer look.

Comment: @pmdj, `ctl_enqueuedata` returns 0 all time.

Comment: did it work? L,